# What is a device tree and a device tree blob?

Tags: linux, devices, device-tree

What exactly is a device tree, and a device tree blob? Where can I get its source code for a particular linux version?  I found such name while running linux on xilinx chips (having ARM 9), for example: [here](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Build+Device+Tree+Blob)

Comment: Are you referring to the device/hardware description stuff used on, e.g., ARM?

Comment: yes. I sw this while running linux on ARM 9 based xilinx chips

Comment: I've only heard of them, not really dealt with them. Basically, it's something passed from the firmware or bootloader to the kernel, to tell it what hardware exists on the system. Here are a few links: http://elinux.org/Device_Tree https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried consulting the Xilinx wiki?

- [Build Device Tree Blob](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Build+Device+Tree+Blob)

This howto looks like it has everything you need to get what you want. There's links to a git repository with code as well as directions on how to build it. Here's the command to download the device-tree sources.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/Xilinx/device-tree.git
```

The Xilinx website also provides a excellent [Getting Started](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Getting+Started) resource if you're new to their toolhchain workflow. Here's a diagram that shows where the device trees fit in:

[image: ss of xilinx workflow]

Given these details a very specific to a variance of Linux for the Xilinx platform I'm not going to include any of the details beyond the above here on U&L, since that wiki is maintained by a hardware vendor, Xilinx, that's supporting that version of the kernel for their hardware products to use.

Answer (score 4):

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22device+tree+blob%22) refers to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_tree), which refers to [www.devicetree.org](http://www.devicetree.org/) which describes your "device tree" as:

> The Device Tree is a data structure for describing hardware. Rather
>   than hard coding every detail of a device into an operating system,
>   many aspect of the hardware can be described in a data structure that
>   is passed to the operating system at boot time. The device tree is
>   used both by Open Firmware, and in the standalone Flattened Device
>   Tree (FDT) form.

Seems like this is a completely different "device tree" than the "device tree" under `/dev/`.

Answer (score 3):

**Minimal `reg` + `interrupt` example with QEMU virtual device**

As others said, the device tree is provided by hardware vendors, and it tells the Linux kernel how to talk to devices.

Maybe the two most notable pieces of information that the Linux kernel needs are:

- register addresses. In ARM-land, you talk to devices by writing to magic physical memory locations that go to the device instead of memory. This is how you tell the device to start working.
- interrupt line numbers. This is how the device tells the kernel it has finished doing something.

Our example will add the following device tree node to the `versatilepb` device tree which QEMU will use due to `-M versatilepb`:

```
lkmc_platform_device@101e9000 {
    compatible = "lkmc_platform_device";
    reg = <0x101e9000 0x1000>;
    interrupts = <18>;
    interrupt-controller;
    #interrupt-cells = <2>;
    clocks = <&pclk>;
    clock-names = "apb_pclk";
    lkmc-asdf = <0x12345678>;
};
```

Then, by using a Linux kernel module to interact with the device, we will test the following DTS features:

- registers addresses
- IRQs
- read custom properties from the driver

These are the main components of the example:

- [Linux versatile `.dts` patch on Linux fork](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/blob/361bb623671a52a36a077a6dd45843389a687a33/arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dts#L42)

  - `reg` and `interrupt` match numbers hard-coded in the QEMU versatile machine (which represents the SoC)
  - `compatible` matches the `platform_driver.name` in the kernel module, and informs the kernel which module will handle this device
  - we also pass a custom property to the driver: `lkmc-asdf = <0x12345678>;`, which is read with `of_property_read_u32`
  - the device tree is passed to QEMU's firmware with the `-dtb` argument
- QEMU fork:

  - [device](https://github.com/cirosantilli/qemu/blob/144ea94d710c666babd06ed733007377e132ed4a/hw/misc/lkmc_platform_device.c) that reads a register and generates interrupts
  - [insert device into `-M versatilepb`](https://github.com/cirosantilli/qemu/blob/144ea94d710c666babd06ed733007377e132ed4a/hw/arm/versatilepb.c#L302)
- [kernel module](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/05fa0105eaccf37d6a675f9b2bae833fd78d4270/kernel_module/platform_device.c) Writes to memory on probe to test things out, which also generates an IRQ.

Device trees have many more features that we haven't covered, but this example should get you started, and easily allow you to play around with any new features that come up.

Further resources:

- indispensable elinux tutorial: http://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage
- play around with `dtc` for purely syntaxical questions. E.g., it shows how nodes are simply merged by path: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375923/32558
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488320/how-to-program-linux-dts-device-tree-files