# Is the device tree compiler tied to the kernel version?

Tags: linux-kernel, devices, device-tree

I have a situation in which same device trees are used with different kernels.
Can the device trees be build only once and used with all kernels?

The reason I ask this is because I found the device tree compiler having a separate repository that the kernel.
Also the explanation from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/what-is-a-device-tree-and-a-device-tree-blob) doesn't relate device tree compilation directly to a kernel version.

Comment: Vague. Device Tree could refer to Repository Source Code or The Structure Describing System Hardware. Here, the user meant Structure Describing System Hardware.

Comment: @TylerMaginnis Uh? No, “device tree” in a Linux kernel context is a structure describing hardware. A source code tree would not be called “device tree” but “kernel source code” or just possibly “driver (source) tree”.

Comment: The reference to compiler in this question mislead me to answer this in the context of kernel driver tree. I believe the answer here is that each Kernel you compile can only have one device tree. So you can build it twice (the device tree) in two different Kernels.

Comment: @TylerMaginnis I'm pretty sure the OP is asking whether or not a dtb compiled for, say, 3.14 could be used for a 3.16 kernel. And I'm 95% sure the answer is yes, but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After being in a situation where this could be tested I've witnessed that you can't use a device tree compiled for kernel 3.10 on kernel 3.14. and vice versa.