# how to merge device tree overlays to a single .dtb at build time?

Tags: kernel, device-tree

My board boots via U-Boot and AFAIK that bootloader does not support *device tree overlays*, so I'm probably forced to generate a **single, static** `.dtb` will all relevant overlays (and settings??) already applied to it. In principle that would be okay for me, but how to do that?

Is there some command line tool that takes `.dtb` and `.dtbo` files resp. `.dts` and `.dtsi` files and combines them into a single `.dtb` / `.dts`?

[`dtc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dtc.1.html) doesn't seem to do that job.

The ultimate goal is to [get I²C working on a Raspberry B+ that boots *via U-Boot*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/41277/40083).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this.

With this change, overlays are in u-boot!
https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/commit/e6628ad7b99b285b25147366c68a7b956e362878

Enjoy :)

Comment: @dr01 the link is pointing to a particular commit in the u-boot code. it isn't pointing to the answer. What this answer is saying (as far as I can tell) is that updating `u-boot` is all that's needed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the dts makes merging trivial: all you need to do is to cat or `#include` the separate dts, because:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    a;
};

/ {
    b;
};
```

is the same as:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
        a;
        b;
};
```

because both specify a property for node `/`.

This can be observed with:

```
dtc a.dts
```

on the first `dts` above.

I couldn't however found a more automated way to do this with the Linux kernel build system yet.